# What type of boundary (if any) problem for this family of elliptic PDEs? "half boundary"?

Tags: terminology, elliptic-pde, linear-pde, stochastic-differential-equations

Classic literature for a general elliptic PDE with Dirichlet boundary condition is typically studied with the following set up: Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ be some open bounded domain and $\partial \Omega$ its boundary and consider for $L$ elliptic operator the following homogeneous Dirichlet boundary PDE for sufficiently regular functions $f$
$$ Lu = f \quad on \,\, \Omega $$
$$ u = 0 \quad on \, \, \partial \Omega$$

This problem is well-studied especially under the assumption of uniformly ellipticity. 

 
 Now, my question concerns the following: suppose we are on $R^2$ for simplicity and have explicitly a rectangular domain
$$ \Omega = (a,b) \times (c,d)$$ 
then the boundary is all four sides of the rectangle i.e.
$$ \partial \Omega = \partial \Omega_1 \cup \partial \Omega_2 \cup \partial \Omega_3 \cup \partial \Omega_4 $$
Where we defined for ease $\partial \Omega_1 = \big\{a\big\}\times [c,d]$, $\partial \Omega_2 = \big\{b \big\}\times [c,d]$, $\partial \Omega_3 = [a,b]\times \big\{c \big\}$ and $\partial \Omega_4 = [a,b]\times \big\{d\big\} $. Suppose, we have the same elliptic operator $L$ and consider the PDE:

$$ Lu = f \quad on \,\, \Omega $$
$$ u = 0 \quad on  \,\, \partial \Omega_1 \cup \partial \Omega_2$$
And $u$ does **not** have prescribed data on $\partial \Omega_3$ nor $\partial \Omega_4$ and treated as unknown to be solved for.

 **Question**: Is there a name for this type of "half" boundary problem? More to point, is the PDE even solvable with these boundary condition (assuming uniformly ellipticity)? If not, does imposing "symmetric boundary condition" in that $u|_{\partial \Omega_3} = u|_{\partial \Omega_4}$ i.e. for any $x \in [a,b]$ we have $u(x,c) = u(x,d)$, is it solvable now? A name and any references to this type of boundary problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess on the boundary you mean $u=0$ instead of $Lu=0$.

Comment: The solution is definitely not unique. Consider the harmonic function $u=\sin x\sinh y$.

Comment: @FanZheng, Yes, I meant $u=0$ rather than $Lu=0$ on the boundary - edited. How did you deduce non-uniqueness from your example  -the fact it is not a "complete" Dirichlet boundary?

Comment: Choose $a$ and $b$ such that $\sin a=\sin b=0$. Choose $c$ and $d$ such that $\sinh c$, $\sinh d\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you, Fan Zheng. I suppose the point is that contrasting with well-known literature that one needs $u=0$ (say) on the entire boundary $\partial \Omega$ to ensure uniqueness of solution (in the case of uniformly elliptic operator anyway).

Comment: If you represent $u$ stochastically using a Feynman-Kac formula,  then you could describe the Dirichlet boundary conditions on $\partial \Omega_1 \cup \partial \Omega_2$ as **absorbing**, and the remaining ones as **unattainable** by the process with generator $L$.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee: Actually, that is essentially the problem I am trying to solve in that I started with a SDE and now trying to solve its PDE counterpart. I think from what I've done, it is attainable under some assumption on L.

Comment: If $\partial \Omega_3 \cup \partial \Omega_4$ are attainable, then don't you have to specify boundary conditions on the process?  In particular, what does the process do when it hits $\partial \Omega_3 \cup \partial \Omega_4$?

Comment: Long story shorter: For a bounded open set $\Omega$ and some stochastic generator $L$ of an autonomous SDE, it is known that solving $Lu=-1$ on $\Omega$ satisfying boundary condition $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$ solves $u$ for expected hitting time. In the case of non-autonomous SDE, the Markov transition function is no longer time-homogeneous which traditionally is used to derive the above PDE. To regain the homogeneity, I considered the spacetime coordinates $(t,X_t)$ which is now time-homogeneous. Perhaps surprisingly, $L'u=-1$ for $L'$ on this spacetime space.

Comment: In the original space I had $u=0$  on $ \partial \Omega$ but in this spacetime space, as it includes the variable itself, it is essentially as I written in the above question of having only data only prescribed on the "two sides of the rectangle" rather than the top/bottom where the y-axis is understood as time. For attainability, I assumed some conditions on the Markov transition kernel to attain the expected hitting is finite a.s..

Comment: @zasderf The operator $L'$ is of degenerate elliptic type.  No? (PS: please include my handle in your response, otherwise I won't see it.)

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee, Yes, $L'$ is degenerate, specifically along $(s,0)$ for nonzero $s$.